# Do tempo do Ronca

Tags: expressões, regionalismo, informalidade

No Rio de Janeiro há uma expressão muito usada para se referir a algo que é muito antigo: "**do tempo do Ronca**". Por exemplo, imaginem dois colegas numa conversa:

```
- Lembra daqueles calhambeques?
- Ih, isso é do tempo do Ronca!
```

Alguém sabe o que é o "Ronca"?

Comment: Não só no RJ. Já ouvi muito isso no NE

Comment: @jean, obrigado pelo seu comentário!

Comment: Já vi que este tópico é muito discutido por essa net fora. Muita gente diz que *o tempo do Ronca* é uma variante de *o tempo do Onça*, que foi como ficou conhecido um governador português do Rio de Janeiro no século XVIII, e que os cariocas detestaram.

Comment: Como nativo do Rio de Janeiro e tendo aqui vivido durante .......... bem, deixa pra lá.  A verdade é que nunca, repito, nuca ouvi "o tempo do Ronca".  Acho que há um exagero em dizer "uma expressão muito usada".  Quanto a "do tempo do Onça" ouvia muito a geração passada (meus pais, tios e avós) usá-la, nos anos sessenta e setenta.  Já não ouço tanto hoje em dia.

Comment: @Centaurus Pelo contrário, eu nunca ouvi ninguém dizer "do tempo do Onça", mas, pelo comentário do Jacinto, a expressão deve ter sido transformada! Eu não vivo mais no Rio há alguns anos, mas ouvia com alguma regularidade, da boca de velhos e novos, tanto no meu círculo mais familiar quanto na escola.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trata-se da deturpação de tempo do Onça. Mas que Onça seria esse? No Rio de Janeiro do século 18, havia um chefe de polícia muito rigoroso. Por isso, foi apelidado de Onça. O xerife fez fama. Mesmo com outros chefes de polícia mais tolerantes, falava-se nele. Quando se reclamava contra as transgressões da lei, diziam:
— Isso era no tempo do Onça.
Com o passar dos anos, o significado mudou. Hoje designa coisas antigas, de anos idos e vividos. Do tempo do Onça.

**Fonte:** Blog de Mário Negócio. Disponível em:
http://mnegocio.blog.uol.com.br/arch2007-11-18_2007-11-24.html.
Publicado em 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Ronca era um trecho entre Balsas e Riachão no Maranhao, nesse “Tempo do Ronca” só se conseguia fazer o trajeto com tábuas colocadas encima da estrada de areia, um verdadeiro deserto, inclusive toda viagem só chegava ao destino final com a ajuda de um “batedor” altamente conhecedor da região.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas, por exemplo com referências — seria ótimo se você pudesse adicionar alguma.